# CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE returns wrong value

Tags: opencl

Querying device information with clGetDeviceInfo() using CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE returns 1GB even though RAM is 2GB. Device type = CPU. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think it *must* return your available RAM?

The OpenCL implementation is free to return whatever it wants.

Comment: really? why is that? which means upgrading to 4GB is useless?! :(

Comment: No, it's not useless, is just a number returned by the implementation. It probably can (and will) use more memory than that.

Comment: You can try creating memory objects to fill the limit. make sure each object is smaller than CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE. After you pass the memory limit, you are likely to get an out-of-resources error